# Flutter: Parsing Json with special characters (utf-8)

Tags: php, json, parsing, flutter, utf-8

I have a pretty basic php code that generates a JSON file with some data:

```
$json = json_encode($theData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('api.json', $json);
```

When I parse it in my Flutter app, it returns special characters and not characters like "éóáêô".

I was parsing json file in Flutter like this:

```
var data = await http.get("xxxx/api.json", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
if (data.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Status Code 200: Ok!');
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
```

Then, I figure out that changing:

```
json.decode(data.body);
```

by:

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
```

Solved the problem!

**Question is: Why using utf8.decode and bodyBytes solved the problem? Am I creating the JSON file with PHP properly?**

Comment: Where does `$theData` come from? It sounds like there may be an issue with how the data is stored or with how your PHP scripts access it.

Comment: $theData is basically an array that I created. It`s a basic json structure. The content has many special characters like "éóáêô".

Comment: Then I'm writing into a ".json" file in my shared-host sever. Then I'm parsing into Flutter app.

Comment: thanks - `json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes))` did it. I am very glad

Answer (score 5):

You're able to fetch the http [Response](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html) body by using either `Response.body` or `Response.bodyBytes`. The advantage of using **bodyBytes** is it fetches the bytes directly. Common uses for this is if you're expecting images to be displayed through parsing bytes. With **body** - this is commonly used if you're expecting plain Strings.

Since you're expecting special characters from the http response, it's best to fetch its bytes directly before using `utf8.decode()`

```dart
json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was this :

```
var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
      var text = unescape.convert(response.body);
      print(text);
      final data = jsonDecode(text);
```

using this : https://pub.dev/packages/html_unescape